# TYPO3 V7.6, default value for Number of Columns

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

How is it possible to set in Page TSConfig the default value for "Number of Columns" in TYPO3 V7.6? In erlier versions it was possible with `TCEFORM.tt_content.imagecols = 1`. If I set in V7.6 `TCEFORM.tt_content.imagecols = 1` it makes no different which value is set. There is always `imagecols = 2` set.

I have PHP 7.0.7 and use the rendering extension fluid_styled_content (not css_styled_content). Is there something I am missing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The rendering extension does not have influence on stuff configured via `TCEFORM`, which is only relevant for the default value in backend forms (FormEngine, formerly known as TCEforms.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to set the number of columns in the frontend or do you want to set the default value provided in the form?

Comment: I'd like to achieve in the backend form for content element "text & media", that "number of columns" in tab appearance is set for default value to 1.

Comment: I’ll check that later today, sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Thank you, that's very kind.

Comment: I just tried that on 6.2 and 7.6, and it did not work on both. I looked it up in the manual and according to https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TCEform/Index.html#tceform, the following should work: `TCEFORM.tt_content.imagecols.config.default = 5`—but it doesn’t.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I checked the configration in $GLOBALS['TCA'] (Table configuration array). There it shows default value in **tt_content.columns.imagecols.config.default = 2** . That seems to be the correct default value. So I tried following setting: TCEFORM.tt_content.columns.imagecols.config.default = 1. But it doesn't override the default value?!

Comment: Yes. I think this either never worked (because it also did not on 6.2) or we have a long outstanding bug here.

Comment: Yes it looks like a long outstanding issue. If I remember me correctly, it worked for sure in V4.5.

Comment: There is a solution, if there is an extension, which can be used. I added in a new extension I created as follows: a) a new folder Configuration\TCA\**Overrides** b) a new file in this folder **tt_content.php** c) in this file I wrote one line: $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['imagecols']['config']['default'] = 1; . That works as expectetd :-). Well there is still the unanswerde question, how can we achieve this only with typoscript?!

Comment: Ok, if its good for you to have that set globally, then of course TCA overrides work fine :-) As for the TSconfig solution, I would need to check that again. It’s possible that this got lost somewhere between 4.5 and 6.2…

Comment: Yes at the moment it is alright. I don't mind if you could keep it cheking as soon as you have the time for it. Somehow or other, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
TCAdefaults.tt_content.imagecols = 1
```

works for me in TYPO3 7.6.11

`TCEFORM.tt_content.imagecols.config.default = 1` is not working, as described op.

Be aware: This config never works if you switch content type after saving a content:

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/75233

Comment: Ok, thank you for your hint. That is still defective and not stable for all situations, as you mentioned. Hopefully it will fixed in a further update.